Unable to add members to a mail-enabled security group using PowerShell Script
I am connected to Exchange Online via PowerShell and I'm trying to add a bulk list of members via a CSV file. The below script is what I have used and the error keeps pointing back to the member argument is null. I used a Write-Host to verify that the columns in the CSV file was actually read (originally it was trying to read the entire column as one member)
Import CSV file
$users = Import-Csv -Path "C:\Scripts\Code2_list.csv"

Mail-enabled security group name
$mailEnabledSecurityGroup = "Code2_License_Management"

Add users to the security group
foreach ($user in $users) {
    $userEmail = $user | Select-Object -ExpandProperty userPrincipalName

Assuming the email address field is named 'userPrincipalName'
Write-Host "User email: $userEmail"    

Print the extracted email address
Add-DistributionGroupMember -Identity $mailEnabledSecurityGroup -Member $userEmail
}
Output error from PowerShell.
Add-DistributionGroupMember : Cannot validate argument on parameter 'Member'. The argument is null. Provide a valid
value for the argument, and then try running the command again.
At line:14 char:77
+ ... ionGroupMember -Identity $mailEnabledSecurityGroup -Member $userEmail
+                                                                ~~~~~~~~~~
    + CategoryInfo          : InvalidData: (:) [Add-DistributionGroupMember], ParameterBindingValidationException
    + FullyQualifiedErrorId : ParameterArgumentValidationError,Add-DistributionGroupMember


Is the UPN actually the email address? Is there a blank value at the top of the list of Users? Or is the value actually called "userPrincipalName"? Does it need to be expanded (if it's just in a CSV it probably doesn't need to be expanded. It is telling you the value is empty, so you should probably look at your data because that's probably what's wrong here.

In your loop, make a line of just $userEmail within it, and confirm that what is spit out is indeed the value which -Member $userEmail is expecting. Based on the error, that value is NULL and you cannot use the command with that argument value not being an actual value. If your csv file has a header/column definition, you may have to loop it with that column value specified e.g. foreach ($user in $users.UniversalPrincipalName) or whatever that column value it set for the value you are passing that command in the loop. So $users.UniversalPrincipalName or $users."some space value".

It looks like the error you’re encountering in PowerShell is due to the variable being null at the time you’re trying to use it in the cmdlet. This means that no value is being assigned to , or the value is not being captured correctly before it’s used as a parameter. $userEmail Add-DistributionGroupMember $userEmail

It has been a while and I am writing to see how things are going on with this issue. Have you had a chance to check the replies provided? Any update would be appreciated.
